# How to load a simple React NPM component into application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-component

I am trying to load a simple React component into my application (specifically, [React-rating](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-rating)).

I run Visual Studio, and have made sure to add it to my `packages.json`, and install all the dependencies (see the image in the bottom of post).

Now, I try to follow the standard instruction for using the component. In the top of my TSX file I write:

```
var Rating = require('react-rating');
```

And when I use the component, I just use `<Rating />`

Now, this gives:

```
TS2604: JSX element type 'Rating' does not have any construct or call signatures.
```

If I instead load the module like this:

```
import * as Rating from 'react-rating';
```

Then I get:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-rating'. '/Likvido.CreditRisk/node_modules/react-rating/lib/react-rating.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/react-rating` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-rating';`
```

I guess it's because I use Typescript, but in that case, how do I import the component?

My dependencies:

[image]

Comment: Did you try `import Rating from 'react-rating';` ?

Comment: @Striped Yes :) Forgot to mention. This results in : TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-rating'. 'Likvido.CreditRisk/node_modules/react-rating/lib/react-rating.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try npm install @types/react-rating if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module 'react-rating';

Comment: It seems that you need to install the typings/types for the package. However, if it doesn't exist, so you may need to create it yourself.

Comment: @Striped Being a complete newbie, is it possible you can either elaborate or maybe send a link where I can learn more? :-) Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is lot of similar issues with types on SO, google `Could not find a declaration file for module` and you'll find what you need.

Comment: Well, did you try creating a `global.d.ts` file with `declare module 'react-rating';`? That's what the error message is telling you (same thing Striped mentioned above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying problem was because I didn't properly install packages.

I stopped using the package console inside Visual Studio when installing packages, but instead made sure the NPM was in my Path. Then I used the normal console opened by running `cmd` on `ctrl+r` (and of course navigating to the correct solution).

When you install the packages here, they will arrive properly inside Visual Studio with everything installed so they work.